# Background video on hover Elementor container

Tags: javascript, css, hover, elementor

I need to add a hover effect on a container in Elementor. I haver a container with information and need to add a background video when hovering the container. Do anyone know if it is possible to do it with css?
thanks

I asked chatgpt because I'm not very familiar with javascript but te code doesn't work.

```
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var semilla = document.getElementById('semilla');
    var videoHover = document.createElement('video');
    
    videoHover.autoplay = true;
    videoHover.loop = true;
    videoHover.muted = true;
    
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    source.src = 'http://www.narcisa.com.mialias.net/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/semilla.mp4';
    source.type = 'video/mp4';
    
    videoHover.appendChild(source);
    semilla.appendChild(videoHover);
    
    semilla.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    videoHover.style.display = 'block';
    videoHover.play();
    });
    
    semilla.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    videoHover.pause();
    videoHover.style.display = 'none';
    });
    });
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Please add a video element on the same content where you want the hover effect and position it absolute with top,left,right and bottom as 0.Then make it's display:none;

and on hover make it display:block 

You can try using transition property and opacity to adjust the smoothness

Hope This helps